# Angular MSal conditionally disable route guard based on environment variable

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, auth-guard

I have a routing module set up as shown below where I use MsalGuard to require authentication before accessing child routes.  This works, however, when I'm testing locally I would like to have the MsalGuard be disabled based on an environment variable.

How can I accomplish this?

I have tried using canDeactivate on my route (commented out below) and passing an Authguard service that returns true or false, but this does not seem to do what I need.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 't',
    component: TabsPage,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard], //when testing locally I am just commenting this out, however I would like to have this guard not be active if I have an environment variable that is set to true for disableAuth
    canDeactivate: [AuthGuard], //I tried setting an auth guard service that does all the authentication checks and returns a true/false based on whether the user is logged in and also sends false if the disableAuth is set to true, but this does not work as I was hoping
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operation for conditional guard config.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 't',
    component: TabsPage,
    canActivate: environment.condition ? [MsalGuard] : []
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
      },
    ]
  }
];
```